# C++ - Program to count occurrences of word without ifstream

Tags: c++, string, count, ifstream, cpu-word

I have a code where the program will read a word from user and then count its total occurrence in a text file “my_data.txt”. But I don't want to use the ifstream function. I already have a text like "the sky is blue".

I want the program to read from that. I know I can create a string and add the text but how can I count the occurrences?

Here is my code so far:

```
    #include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
 ifstream fin("my_data.txt"); //opening text file
 int count=0;
 char ch[20],c[20];

 cout<<"Enter a word to count:";
 gets(c);

 while(fin)
 {
  fin>>ch;
  if(strcmp(ch,c)==0)
   count++;
 } 

 cout<<"Occurrence="<<count<<"\n";
 fin.close(); //closing file

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `std::ifstream`? And since you don't, why do you tag this [tag:ifstream]? And would `std::fstream` be OK since it is not `std::ifstream`?

Comment: @BaummitAugen inb4 homework, although i agree if you cant use X feature, don't tag X

Comment: Whats wrong with the code you have so far besides the fact the you are using the wrong includes for standard C++?

Comment: You want to read a from a file but dont want to use `std::ifstream`?..

Comment: _@moose_ So you mean you want to use something like [`fscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) instead?

Comment: You can use `cin` and have your OS redirect the output of the text file to the standard input of your program.

Comment: You can't use `gets()` with `ifstream`; bad karma to cross C++ streams with C streams.  Use `gets()` with `FILE *` and `std::string` with `ifstream`.

Comment: Also, `gets` is dangerous since it can overflow the buffer.  It reads as many characters until the end of line is detected.  If you type in 32 characters, it will overflow your array of 20.  Use `fgets` instead; or better yet, use `ifstream`.

Comment: I really don't understand why you don't use `std::string`.  By the way, if either of your arrays is not nul, '\0', terminated, the compare function may go past the array looking for the first difference or a nul character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without using `ifstream`, you have some choices:  `cin` and `piping`; or `fscanf`.  *I really don't understand why you don't want to use `ifstream`.*

### `cin` and Piping

You can use the `cin` stream and let the OS rout the data file to your program.

You loop would look something like this:

```
std::string word;
while (cin >> word)
{
  // process the word
}
```

An example invocation using a command line is:

```
my_program.exe < my_data.txt
```

This invocation tells the Operating System to redirect the standard input to a driver that reads from the file `my_data.txt`.

### Using `fscanf`

The `fscanf` comes from the C background and can be used to read from files.  Developing the correct *format specifier* for a *word* can be tricky.  But it isn't `std::ifstream`.

Also, `fscanf` cannot be safely used with the `std::string`, whereas `std::ifstream` can be used safely with `std::string`.

### Edit 1: Words From a String

Since there is some ambiguity in your question, one interpretation is that you want to count words from a string of text.

Let's say you have a declaration like this:
`const std::string sentence = "I'm hungry, feed me now.";`

You could use `std::istringstream` and count the words:

```
std::string word;
std::istringstream sentence_stream(sentence);
unsigned int word_count = 0U;
while (sentence_stream >> word)
{
  ++word_count;
}
```

Comment: No, I mean I don't want to route the text file to my program. I just want to count the occurences that are in my string variable. Don't want to read from a text file.

Comment: Better edit your question, @moose , because reading a file and counting instances of a user-provided word sounds exactly like what you are asking.

Comment: @moose:  See my **Edit 1:** section.  I describe how to get words out of a string.  I can make it more complicated if you'd like.